# how to hide widgets from blogger label search

Tags: html, widget, blogger

How do i hide element from showing in my label search result only.
I have tried all ways but the css i got to use will only hide on all the pages. I also used different article but it hide widget on specific pages, blog post and not label search result
I want some or all widget/element within my **label search** to be hidden without hiding all the elements or widgets that appear in home. Please note i don't want to hide widgets or element in home but label result. I want the label result to just have the list of post within the label

Here is the label link search result which shows all element in home before showing my label post. I just want the label post https://quickrecruitng.blogspot.com/search/label/Administrative%20Officer

Answer (score 0):

To target label pages, use the following

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel'>
  <!-- all label pages -->
</b:if>

<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == "foo"'>
  <!-- for label 'foo' -->
</b:if>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response but what do I do with the line of code you posted. How do I out it to work to achieve what i want

Comment: The challenge is that most of the things i want to hide are not widgets but elements covered with div. See the url i previously sent to see the front end or look at my back end code https://snag.gy/Z3Fsqr.jpg

Comment: To hide elements on label pages add them between `<b:if cond='!data:blog.searchLabel'> your elements here </b:if>` note `!`